# Got this error while running npm install : Not Found - GET http://registry.npmjs.org/react 'react@^15.3.0 || ^16.0.0-alpha' is not in this registry

Tags: javascript, npm

[error in my terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udruJ.png)

i tried to run 'npm install' and i received the error 'Not Found - GET http://registry.npmjs.org/react 'react@^15.3.0 || ^16.0.0-alpha' is not in this registry.'

Comment: Can you add the package.json file?